# Can SuperpoweredAdvanceAudioPlayer work invoked from Swift?

Tags: swift, superpowered

I have a Swift project that has successfully bridged into much SuperPowered functionality (accessing waveform, BPM, Key).
Now I'm trying to use SuperpoweredAdvanceAudioPlayer to play back. I've followed my existing patterns to access the library from Swift. It's compiling but no audio is playing.
I have seen this comment [here](https://github.com/detourhub/detour-android-audio-engine) 
"Swift note:
We have also tried creating this project in Swift, but itÕs not complete for audio and several features were impossible to implement (such as proper performance measurement). Swift is not designed for real-time audio. Fortunately, Objective-C++ files work great in Swift projects."

Should I interpret that as meaning it's not possible to play in SuperpoweredAdvanceAudioPlayer called from Swift?

Just would like to know before I spend more time trying to figure out if it's a problem with my code.

If the answer is "yes it should be possible" the I can post up some code

Comment: I had not used it, if you could share Xcode Project  we developers here can have a look and try to solve issue

Comment: Sounds like a better question to ask on the project's GitHub issues than here. If you want help with something specific, provide some code.

Comment: I believe that Superpowered do their support from SO?

Answer (score 0):

Try the SuperpoweredFrequencies example project in the SDK, it shows how to bridge between Swift and Objective-C++.